# Trying to use variable in calculation for html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate something and add it to an html page as an element. However, when I try to add a variable within the calculation, it doesn't work. What am I doing

```
$("#hours_copper").html(addCommas(roundTo( (100/chanceToWinPerNode.copper)/(60*(60/insertanyvariable)) , 2) ));
```

insertanyvariable is where I'm trying to put the variable in. The rest of it just has to do with a bunch of layers and something that is already calculated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `addCommas()` return a value?

Comment: addCommas() is just a separate function to add commas, as long as I remove the variable from the equation everything works flawlessly. variable borks it.

Comment: update question and add full code of `addComas, roundTo` and example values of `chanceToWinPerNode.copper` and `insertanyvariable`

Answer (score 0):

Try use innerHTML

```js
let calcVal = 66.6; 
hours_copper.innerHTML = calcVal;
```

```html
<div id="hours_copper"></div>
```

Comment: innerHTML works standalone but so do other ways, the issue is mixing the variable into the calculation